# How to run SVN commands from a python script?

Tags: python, svn

Basically I want to write a python script that does several things and one of them will be to run a checkout on a repository using subversion (SVN) and maybe preform a couple more of svn commands. What's the best way to do this ? This will be running as a crond script.

Comment: Have you taken a look to [Python Interface for Subversion](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn.html)?

Comment: I did not needed it but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Would this work?

```
p = subprocess.Popen("svn info svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/project/trunk | grep \"Revision\" | awk '{print $2}'", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
print "Revision is", output
```

Comment: @Ricardo If you are going to use this technique I think it would be simpler if the output is requested as XML. Something like `svn info --xml`. That way results will be simpler to parse and process.

Answer (score 16):

Try [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn.html)

Gives you great access as far as i've tested it.
Here's some examples: http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_guide.html

The reason for why i'm saying as far as i've tested it is because i've moved over to Git.. but if i recall pysvn is (the only and) the best library for svn.

Comment: Actually, there are two python modules for subversion: pysvn and svn (SWIG lib around subversion C lib): http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.developer.usingapi.html#svn.developer.usingapi.otherlangs   Depending on what you are trying to do, most people use pysvn.

Comment: It seems like the pysvn site will be soon gone, a message now warns "**2020-03-13: This site is going to be decommissioned and shut down very soon. Please copy and archive any data you wish to keep ASAP**".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the python xonsh module: http://xon.sh/tutorial.html

It can call shell commands plus piping and output redirection with close touch to the python native code (nested) without need to play with python communicate bullshet and escape characters around.

**Examples**:

`env | uniq | sort | grep PATH`

`COMMAND1 e>o < input.txt | COMMAND2 > output.txt e>> errors.txt`

`echo "my home is $HOME"`

`echo @(7+3)`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ashutoshkr9329/svn

The SVN Update Script (svn.py) is a Python-based tool designed to automate the execution of svn update commands across multiple projects. This script simplifies the process of updating checked-out repositories, saving time and effort for users managing multiple SVN projects.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35655216)